# validating file types from array

Tags: php

```
if ( isset( $_FILES['upload'] ) ) {
    $name_array = $_FILES['upload']['name']; 
    $size_array = $_FILES['upload']['size'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
    $ext = substr($upload, strrpos($upload, '.') + 1);
    $allowed = array('image/jpeg:jpg','image/pjpeg:jpg','image/gif:gif','image/png:png');
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];

    if (!in_array($_FILES['uploaded']['type'], $allowed)){

    exit("unsupported");
    }


            if ( move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name_array[$i], "uploaded/" . $name_array[$i] ) ) {
                    echo "Image $name_array[$i] uploaded<br>";
            } else {
                    echo "Image #$i left blank<br>";
            }
    }
```

what exactly am I doing wrong? I could really do with some help. thanks. If it is not clear what I am trying to achieve is validation on 3 uploaded images from an array

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: I just can't get it to work no error

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve restrictions on upload then see example below.

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png"); //Set allowed file extensions
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp); //Get file extension of the file being uploaded

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") //check if file is allowed
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)            //check the size of the file
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) { //check if the extension is in the array
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {

    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";

  } else {

    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) { 

      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";

    } else {

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploaded/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);  //move file to specific folder
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploaded/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
  }
} else {

  echo "Invalid file";

}
?>
```

See basic upload restriction on http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0):

In your code i mainly see 2 things that could cause problems:

1.File type check

```
$allowed = array('image/jpeg:jpg','image/pjpeg:jpg','image/gif:gif','image/png:png');
```

Every check against this array should fail as is in format:

```
'image/jpeg', 'image/png'
```

and so on.

If you want to hold extention in array you could use something like this:

```
$allowed = array(
'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',
'image/pjpeg' => 'jpg',
'image/gif' => 'gif',
'image/png' => 'png'
);
//Check if in allowed list
//you can also check like this "if (isset($allowed[strtolower($_FILES['uploaded']['type'])]))"
if (!in_array(strtolower($_FILES['uploaded']['type']), array_keys($allowed)))
{
exit("unsupported");
}
//Get extention
$extention = $allowed[strtolower($_FILES['uploaded']['type'])];
```

2.Moveing uploaded file

```
move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name_array[$i], "uploaded/" . $name_array[$i] )
```

In your case $tmp_name_array[$i] is wrong, should be just $tmp_name_array, as actually it is not an array, it is a string that contains uploaded temp file location on server. $name_array[$i] is also wrong its a string too => original file name. Another suggestion would be to use full path on upload. so i guess it would be better to do:

```
//Useing client sent file name may not be safe to use, so make it safe by removeing unsafe symbols. Example easy way it can be "md5($name_array) . $extention"
$name_array = yourFunctionToMakeFilenameSafe($name_array);
if (!move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name_array, getcwd() . "/uploaded/" . $name_array  )
{
die('failed!');
}
```

Also if that is only image upload feature, i would not relay on client reported file type, as it can be easily faked. So i would use somthing else to determin file real type. I usually do it with imagemagic but you can also use somthing else like php function exif_imagetype and so on.